# U-Substitution, and $\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The original function is:

> $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x+1)}{x+1}$$

If I wanted to use u-substitution to prove that the function has a removable discontinuity at $x=-1$ would I start out by writing this:

> $$f(u-1)=\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$$

Then I using limits I write $\lim_\limits{x \to u-1}f(x)=\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$, then I would take the limit of that as u approaches 0 getting $\lim_\limits{u \to 0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}=1$.  Therefore I can say that the first limit is equal to the second limit hence the function has a removable discontinuity at $x=-1$.  Is the way I proved the removable discontinuity precise, or is there fallacy in my thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning is correct, but nowhere do I see you actually proving that the limit is $1$. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes I did that in the assignment, I left it out because it was trivial at the moment.

Comment: Trivial, with L'hopital's rule and $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$, I assume?